# Add table row with select and options populated by JSON array on click

Tags: jquery, json, append

Currently, my code is on click is outputting nested rows. It does how ever work, but I only want it to be added once per row.

Here's my logic (but could be incorrect):
1. On click do...
2. Add a table row
3. Create my select and options from the validated JSON array
4. Output only once per row

Here's what I'm currently getting when clicking the button over and over:
[image]

Here's my current code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.awccs_admin .section button#add_rate_row', function(){
        var $t = $(this).prev(),
            $tbody = $t.children('tbody'),
            data = ["Lek","؋","$","ƒ","$","₼","$","$","Br","BZ$","$","$b","KM","P","лв","R$","$","៛","$","$","$","¥","$","₡","kn","₱","Kč","kr","RD$","$","£","$","€","£","$","¢","£","Q","£","$","L","$","Ft","kr","","Rp","﷼","£","₪","J$","¥","£","лв","₩","₩","лв","₭","£","$","ден","RM","₨","$","₮","MT","$","₨","ƒ","$","C$","₦","kr","﷼","₨","B\/.","Gs","S\/.","₱","zł","﷼","lei","₽","£","﷼","Дин.","₨","$","$","S","R","₨","kr","CHF","$","£","NT$","฿","TT$","","$","₴","£","$","$U","лв","Bs","₫","﷼","Z$"];

            $tbody.append('<tr><td id="currency"></td></tr>');

            var currency_select = $('<select>').appendTo('td#currency');

            for (var i in data) {
                currency_select.append($('<option/>').html(data[i]));
            }
            $('tr#currency').append('<tr><td>'+currency_select+'</td></tr>');

    });
```

I don't know where I'm going wrong, but I think it might be where I'm creating a DOM element, and then appending another DOM element too it?

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said in the comment you need to keep the id unique. 
Here is a working example : https://jsfiddle.net/d4Lnuywf/

```
var cpt = 0;
$('body').on('click', 'button', function(){
    var $t = $(this).prev(),
        $tbody = $t.children('tbody'),
        data = ["Lek","؋","$","ƒ","$","₼","$","$","Br","BZ$","$","$b","KM","P","лв","R$","$","៛","$","$","$","¥","$","₡","kn","₱","Kč","kr","RD$","$","£","$","€","£","$","¢","£","Q","£","$","L","$","Ft","kr","","Rp","﷼","£","₪","J$","¥","£","лв","₩","₩","лв","₭","£","$","ден","RM","₨","$","₮","MT","$","₨","ƒ","$","C$","₦","kr","﷼","₨","B\/.","Gs","S\/.","₱","zł","﷼","lei","₽","£","﷼","Дин.","₨","$","$","S","R","₨","kr","CHF","$","£","NT$","฿","TT$","","$","₴","£","$","$U","лв","Bs","₫","﷼","Z$"];



        $tbody.append('<tr><td id="currency_'+cpt+'"></td></tr>');
        var currency_select = $('<select>').appendTo('td#currency_'+cpt);
        for (var i in data) {
            currency_select.append($('<option>').html(data[i]));
        }

        cpt = cpt+ 1;
});
```

Comment: Didn't work. But I also need that last bit, because that adds the main row.

Comment: Oh, i've got it. Each time you click on button you add a TD tag with the id : currency, and the next time you click the select will be added to the new tag td and also the old one. Keep in mind that an id need to be unique

Comment: I suggest you add a counter four id, like currency_1, currency_2 etc...

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. Have marked as the answer.